# On resume set previous view

Tags: ios

I have a simple login system for iOS application, when user set focus to password `UITextField` i animate my complete view and move it in viewport of user so user can see field of password. Here is example of how i am doing this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == self.txtPassword)
    {
        CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
        newFrame.origin.y -= 60;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            self.view.frame = newFrame;
        }];
    }
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == self.txtPassword)
    {
        CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
        newFrame.origin.y += 60;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            self.view.frame = newFrame;
        }];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Now my problem is if user exit application (not close) and then resume it, my view is back to normal but textfield is still focused to password box so first animation which starts executing is going down instead to top. How should i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution that will remove the keyboard when the app resign.
From the UX point of view - the user left the app , and the app was "cleared".

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [self.view endEditing:YES];
   CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
   newFrame.origin.y += 60;
   self.view.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

     // Post notification from here to handle


    if ([urTextField isFirstResponder]) {

        [urTextField resignFirstResponder];


    }

}
```

Or follow up this tutorial to access urtextfield through notification center & then dismiss there

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-nsnotification--mobile-10619

Comment: Was thinking about this, but how can i access a property from other "activity" in AppDelegate?

Comment: Is there a ViewController method thath is able to detect thaht app was opened again or loaded? I am realy used to Android so this notification is a bit weird for me.

Comment: in viewdidappear resignfirst responder